# .htaccess Reroute file with hidden parameter to another file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a problem which I'm trying to solve nor for hours.

So in my root director i have a folder called `plugins` with some files in it. The important ones are `plugins.php` and `query.php`.

When the url is /test/plugins I wan't to show the content of `plugins.php`. But when the URL is /test/plugins/param I wan't to keep this URL in the browser but want to show the content of `query.php` and use param with $_GET['param'] in it. Is this possible?

My latest and most promising .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ query.php?param=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ query.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ query.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following htaccess rules file.
Make sure to keep your htaccess rules file inside plugins folder and also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^test/plugins/?$ plugins.php [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^test/plugins/param/?$ query.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, but still not working.

I uploaded the files to a test domain. Therefore https://s775323354.online.de/test/plugins/thisshouldbeget should call query.php but it is still plugins.php.

Comment: @t3chernobyl, what is the sample link you are hitting?